# How to make sure user send right data to firebase callabe function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been working to make sure user send the right data to the firebase HTTPSCallable cloud function.
here is what I got so far:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

class Person {
  name: string;
}

class ExpectingData {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: Person;
  d: Person[];
}

export const example = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const uid = assertUID(context);
  // with "assertUID", I can make sure user is authenticated.
  const a = assertKey(data, "a");
  // With "assertKey", I can roughly make sure user data got the right property in the first nested layer.
  const b = assertKey(data, "b");
  const c = assertKey(data, "c");
  const d = assertKey(data, "d");
});

export const assertUID = (context: any) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "permission-denied",
      "function called without context.auth"
    );
  } else {
    return context.auth.uid as string;
  }
};

export const assertKey = (data: any, key: string) => {
  // data[key] should not be undefined or null;
  const value = data[key];
  if (typeof value === "undefined") {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "invalid-argument",
      `${key} is miisng`
    );
  }
  return value;
};
```

**Here is my question:**
**1.** Is there an assert function that can check if client send exactly the ExpectingData shaped (or of any other shape ) data?
**2.** Is it possible to check typeof a is string and c is instance of Person in this functions, not just cheking the keys (like "assertKey" in example)?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you have to check the properties and types manually to ensure that you have what you want.  It boils down to the fact that TypeScript must compile down to JavaScript, which gives you no guarantees at runtime unless you check them.
2. Any plain JavaScript object (including the ones delivered to your callable) won't have a constructor type that you could check for type safety in TypeScript.  You will have to deeply probe each object and its properties if you want to know if it contains everything you require.  You can certainly use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check for JavaScript strings through using `typeof foo === "string"`.

Comment: Could I recursivly map object properties to check data, somthing like 
  (dataFromClient:any,expectingDataClass:Funcion)=>checkResult.

Comment: I tried, it's frustrating. I need to learn some basic thing.